# Implementation of jump sequence

Tags: c, mips, pipeline

I am trying to implement the jump instruction to my Pipeline Simulator in the **C** language. I have been reading up on the J-Instruction for mips and seen its constructed by 26 bits imm and 6 bits opcode. After some further reading I found that the address to the jump instruction can be calculated using this

```
PC <- PC31-28::IR25-0::00
```

I am not completely sure how I would implement this in the **C** language though. While calculating the ex stage I have been trying something like the code below but it doesn't work for me.

```
if(idStage.instruction.type == J)
{
  ifStage.pc = ifStage << idStage.instruction.imm;
  ifStage.pc = IfStage << 2;
}
```

How could I implement the PC <- PC31-28::IR25-0::00 in the **C** language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be

```
  ifStage.pc = (ifStage.pc & 0xF0000000) | (idStage.instruction.imm << 2);
```

that is: take current PC, apply an AND mask to keep bits 28..31, and then apply an OR mask with the immediate shifter 2 places left.
This assumes idStage.instruction.imm is a 26 bit immediate. If it can hold "garbage" in the high order bits (26..31) then you would apply another AND mask:

```
  ifStage.pc = (ifStage.pc & 0xF000) | ((idStage.instruction.imm & 0x3FFFFFF) << 2);
```